# Check rows in first table, compare them with rows from the second table and output a match

Tags: php, python, sql, select, sqlite

I made my story shorter, as requested.

I am trying to create a time table for students. I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TIMETABLE
(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
YEAR TEXT NOT NULL,
DATE TEXT,
GROUP TEXT,
BEGIN TEXT,
END TEXT,
ROOM TEXT,
SUBJECT TEXT NOT NULL,
TEACHER TEXT,
IN_DATES INT,
TIMESTAMP TIME)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DATES
(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
SUBJECT TEXT NOT NULL,
TEACHER TEXT NOT NULL,
GROUP TEXT,
DATE TEXT,
TIMESTAMP TEXT
```

The first table has all classes for all faculties (e.g. for the first year of studies). The second one contains rows with dates of classes that do not take place weekly (that means, e.g every 2 weeks or with irregular dates).

In short:
If row has `IN_DATES = 0` then we can output it directly.
If row has `IN_DATES = 1` then we need to check if there is a class with the same date and subject in `DATES`. If there is a match, we output the whole row from `TIMETABLE`. If there is no match, we do not display this row.

How to write the SQL query to accomplish this?

My English may not be very good as it is not my native language.

Happy new year ;)

Comment: Please try to make the long story short.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM Timetable t
WHERE in_dates = 0 OR
  (
    in_dates = 1 AND
    EXISTS (
     SELECT 1
     FROM Dates d
     WHERE d.subject = t.subject AND
       d.date = t.date
    )
  )
```

Comment: This query will be more complex (because of e.g. `YEAR` and `GROUP` given from the HTML form). However, thank you very much for the overall concept. I will definitely check this and modify to suit my aforementioned needs.

Comment: All I know is what you put in the question, and if you feel like I've answered that then I'm happy to help :) if not please elaborate in the question so I can understand what more needs to be explained to you. Don't forget to set your question to answered once it is

Comment: OK, I will not forget to marked as answered ;) However, this query returns no classes marked as `IN_DATES = 1` - to be more specific, all `IN_DATES = 1` (those included in `DATES` and those not included) are not displayed. I will try to track down where the problem lies. I mentioned the "more complex" query because I will need to expand your answer - your answer is GREAT ;) I skipped the less important info because the first version of my question was very long (and I got the comment to shorten my story).

Comment: STUPID ME!!! There is no match between subject from both tables because the subject in TIMETABLE contains additional information ;) So I need to replace `d.subject = t.subject` with something like `t.subject LIKE % d.subject %`. Sorry for misinformation.

Comment: I replaced `d.subject = t.subject` with `t.subject LIKE '%' || d.subject || '%'` and it worked! YAY! You are a genius ;) Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Well done on figuring the rest out yourself - good student :)